# For any $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{C}, E(c_1Z+c_2)=c_1E(Z)+c_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

When dealing with real-valued RVs, the extensions of expectation and variance are quite clear to me. For example, showing

$E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b$ and $var(aX+b)=a^2var(X)$ is relatively straightforward to me. Given my weak background in complex numbers, the analogous situation in $\mathbb{C}$ is much more elusive to me.

So, how does one prove (rigorously) the two situations below:

---

$Z:=X+iY$

$\forall c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{C}, E(c_1Z+c_2)=c_1E(Z)+c_2$

$var(Z)=E(|Z|^2)-|E(Z)|^2=var(X)+var(Y)$

---

What is especially confusing (and simultaneously fascinating) is that this result apparently is unaffected by the correlation between $X$ and $Y$. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E(\vert Z\vert)<\infty$ which is the case here since the mean and variance assumed to be well-defined, then the first relation is derived by just linearity of expectation
$$
E(c_1Z) = E(c_1 (X+ j Y)) = E(c_1X + jc_1 Y) = c_1 E(X) + j c_1 E(Y) = c_1 E(Z)
$$
Note that $E(\vert X\vert)< E(\vert Z\vert)<\infty$ and the similar relation is also true for $Y$.

For the second one, let $m_z=E(Z)= m_x + j m_y$:
$$
var(Z) = E((Z-m_z)(Z-m_z)^*) = E((X-m_x + j(Y-m_y))(X-m_x + j (Y-m_y))^*)
$$
Let $U$ be $X-m_x$ and $V$ be $Y-m_y$ the centralized random variables. Then,
$$
Var(Z) = E((U+jV)(U+jV)^*) = E(UU^* -jUV^* +jVU^* + VV^*) = E(U^2) + E(V^2) = var(U) + var(V)  
$$

The third equality is correct since $U$ and $Y$ are real-valued RVs.

Comment: Could you help me with your  notation....is the j representing the complex portion of z? Also what are the "*" denoting?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes (j)^2 = -1. And * is the complex conjugate operator, i.e. (x+j y)* = x - jy for real values x and y.

Comment: where is $c_2$ addressed in the solution for part 1?